# Wildfly redeliver JMS Messages

Tags: jboss, timeout, jms, wildfly, wildfly-8

im using jms in jboss Wildfly 8 for messaging. Message delivered succesfully and Receiver goes on with processing. And it takes about 15-20 Minutes, till Receiver does its job. But  Server redelivers same Message after about 10 minutes. My Question is how and where can i configure Wildfly to  wait for it with for example 20 Mins timelimitations. i found some helpful explenations on Wildfly documentation. But im not sure whether its right way to do this.

[Jboss Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.2.Final/user-manual/en/html/undelivered-messages.html)

[Messaging Configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Messaging+configuration)

should i just add

`<redelivery-delay>1200000</redelivery-delay>
 <max-delivery-attempts>2</max-delivery-attempts>`

in `<address-setting>` in standalone-full.xml

Answer (score 1):

The setting you made is correct. The setting makes the server attempt to deliver messages for another 2 attempts if the first delivery is unsuccessful.

The fact that you be getting the same message several times should be related to the way you're telling the server that the message was processed.

Look at the link below and check that the acknowledge mode is correct with the operating mode of the class that receives the JMS messages.

[JMS Message Delivery Reliability and Acknowledgement Patterns](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/01/jms-message-delivery-reliability-acknowledgement-patterns/)